# Why does my function keep coming back as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

Here is the code I have. I am pretty new to javascript still so I don't see why adding the function stops the for statement from incrementing the integers.

```
const arr = [10,10,16,12]

function incrementByOne(arr) {
  // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
  // return the array


for (const i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[i] += 1;

  
}
return arr
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One issue is your use of `const` in the loop. `i` is supposed to increase, so it shouldn't be a constant.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your browser developer tools console? That is always first step in debugging

Comment: Hi, @charlietfl I've spent probably over an hour trying to debug this in the console before coming here unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work the way I want yet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @fin444. At your suggestion I tried var instead and it is still coming back as undefined. I do appreciate you pointing out this error though.

Comment: OK...just asking as there was no mention of it and always good to tell us "I don't see errors"  You don't show calling the function anywhere as per [mre]. It should work fine changing to `let` from `const`

Comment: Sorry if I came across as be snarky it wasn't my intent. I do genuinely appreciate the advice. I will be more clear in the future regarding what troubleshooting I have already tried.

Comment: No problem. Learning to debug and to think in terms of debugging is just as important if not more important than writing the code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code under Node.js:

Code:

```
'use strict';

const arr = [10,10,16,12]

function incrementByOne(arr) {
    for (const i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] += 1;
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(incrementByOne(arr));
```

Output:

```
$ node incr.js
incr.js:6
        for (const i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at incrementByOne (incr.js:6:37)
$
```

As you can see, it complains that you are trying to change the value of `i` which your code said was constant. Write `let i = 0` for a non-constant value.

Code:

```
'use strict';

const arr = [10,10,16,12]

function incrementByOne(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] += 1;
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(incrementByOne(arr));
```

Output:

```
$ node incr.js
[ 11, 11, 17, 13 ]
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use let i = 0 instead of const i= 0 to initilize the loop iteration counter i

```
const arr = [10,10,16,12]

function incrementByOne(arr) {
  // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
  // return the array


for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[i] += 1;

  
}
return arr
}
```

Then call incrementByOne function

```
incrementByOne(arr);
```

Comment: Where is the explanation of what is changed and why? Code only answers are not very helpful

Comment: I added explanation to my answer :)

Comment: Good start but if I was the OP I might want to know why also

Comment: I think basicaly, since it's a constant and  initialised by 0, it's value will never change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LahEzcen. So far I've tried using let and var and it still comes back as undefined.

Comment: Could you share How do you call incrementByOne function ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use map also:

```
const incrementByOne = (arr) => arr.map((element) => element + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [10,10,16,12]

function incrementByOne(arr) {
    // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
    // return the array


    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] += 1;
    }
    return arr
}
let a = incrementByOne(arr)
console.log(a)
```